# Execution of XSS inside of <p></p> when >< are filtered and cannot escape using ' "

Tags: javascript, html, xss, devtools

I am learning XSS for ethical purposes and I cannot seem to figure this one out on my own. I am trying to use XSS (legally) on a site by appending a `<script>` at the end of the URL. This results in a message saying `Error 404: The page //www.###.com/###/\<script>alert('XSS')\</script> was not found.`. The code in chrome dev tools looks like

```
<div class="text">
    <p>
        "Error 404: The page https://www.###.com/###/<script>alert('XSS')</script> was not found."
    </p>
```

When editing as HTML:

```
Error 404: The page https://www.redditinc.com/press/&lt;script&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;/script&gt; was not found.
```

When I try to break out using ", I get the following:

```
dev tools:

<div class="text">
    <p>
        "Error 404: The page https://www.###.com/###/"<script>alert('XSS')</script> was not found."
    </p>

HTML:

Error 404: The page https://www.redditinc.com/press/"&lt;script&gt;alert('XSS')&lt;/script&gt; was not found.
```

Same thing goes for '.
I'm new to penetration testing, and XSS. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Not here, they are escaping the input correctly.

Comment: Break out of what? An `"` or `'` inside the html text content won't do anything.